# Consulta em mais de uma coluna do mysql com o PHP

Tags: php

Faço assim para fazer uma consulta no banco de dados Mysql

```
$keyword = strval($_POST['query']);
    $search_param = "{$keyword}%";
    $conn =new mysqli('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx' , 'xxx');

    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM empresas WHERE nome LIKE ? or palavras_chave LIKE ?")
    $sql->bind_param("s",$search_param);            
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $countryResult[] = $row["nome"];
        }
        echo json_encode($countryResult);
    }
    $conn->close();
```

Está procurando apenas pelo nome, como eu faria para procurar também outra coluna do mysql? Como por exemplo **nome** e **palavras-chave**.

Comment: ("... nome LIKE ? AND nome = 'alguma coisa'") é isso que você quer? Não entendi muito bem a pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar as condições `and` e `or`.

Exemplo:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM empresas WHERE nome  LIKE ? and palavras-chaves LIKE ?");
```

ou

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM empresas WHERE nome  LIKE ? or palavras-chaves LIKE ?");
```

A escolha vai depender do seu caso específico.

Na hora de substituir os `?` pelos parâmetros, certifique-se de estar colocando `%` antes e depois do valor das variávies.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM empresas WHERE nome  LIKE "%$nome%"
```

tente esse código:

```
$keyword = strval($_POST['query']);
$search_param = "%$keyword%";
$conn =new mysqli('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx' , 'xxx');

$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM empresas WHERE nome LIKE ? or palavras_chave LIKE ?")
$sql->bind_param("ss",$search_param, $search_param); 

$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $countryResult[] = $row["nome"];
    }
    echo json_encode($countryResult);
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: não retorna nada na busca assim

Comment: editei a pergunta, testa de novo

Comment: não está retornando nada na busca, estou fazendo assim $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM empresas WHERE nome LIKE ? or palavras_chave LIKE ?")

Comment: mostra o código do lugar aonde vc substitiu os ? pelos devidos valores

Comment: como falei eh um sistema auto complete, fiz como você falou na resposta, mais nao retorna nada na busca, editei minha pergunta para vc ver o código completo